# Rails - where to store social media links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Where are social media URLs supposed to be located? Right now I am thinking of putting this in `lib`. Is this the right approach, too, or should I put it in a helper, or something else. I feel like I might reference this in the future from outside the view.

Also, if there's a better name than "Marketing", I'll be glad to replace it

```
module MyApp
  class Marketing
    def self.facebook_url
    end

    def self.twitter_url
    end

    def self.tumblr_url
    end

    def self.blog_url
    end
  end
end
```

Test:

```
  scenario 'with MyApp contact information' do
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_content(MyApp::Marketing.blog_url)
    expect(page).to have_content(MyApp::Marketing.facebook_url)
    expect(page).to have_content(MyApp::Marketing.twitter_url)
    expect(page).to have_content(MyApp::Marketing.tumblr_url)
  end
```

Comment: Rails does not have an opinion on that, however, the application helper seems a more appropriate place to me.

Comment: @svoop, thanks for answering. Why do you think so? (First time to do this so I'm curious)

Comment: I made this an answer, however, I'd be interested to hear what others think about this, too.

Answer (score 0):

Rails does not have an opinion on that, however, the application helper seems a more appropriate place to me.

Why? Rails' UrlHelper class seems to be the closest relative, but besides this, it's more of a gut feeling. However, the helpers should be slim, so if you need a lot of code to build the URLs, you might want to move the heavy lifting to a separate class and write one app helper (e.g. social_url :facebook, ...) for all. Where you put this support class is up to you, lib seems like an okay place, other people prefer app/classes. I often extract reusable, clutterish code into vendored gems vendor/gem which keeps the app test suite slim and fast.

Comment: Does Rails load the helper classes when it runs the tests? I guess that's one of the possible things to think about since maybe cluttering up `lib` will slow our test since Rails added it to the load path. But IDK, it's still small at this point... we will see if we need to refactor in the future, but it's nice to know the other options present

Comment: You can test helpers separately and/or as part of the integration tests (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html). But if test suite speed is an issue, then vendored gems with their own test suite are a nice alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't find a conclusive answer, we've used the [rails-config gem](https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config) to create a yml of important information:

```
#config/settings.yml
social:
  facebook: "url"
  twitter: "url"
  linkedin: "url"
  youtube: "url"
  fusion: "url"
```

Then we called the data with a simple helper:

```
  #app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  def setting(option, type)
    record = Option.find_by name: "#{option}_#{type}"
    return record ? record.value : Settings.send(option).send(type)
  end
```

As you can see, we've used a database to give some flexibility, but the bottom line is the `Settings.social.youtube` etc will still be the default option

Comment: Nice. What else would you normally put in the `settings.yml`?

Comment: It's generated by `rails-config` - typically put in `/config`. You should read up about rails-config to see how it works here: https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config